# iOS Let UIGestureGestureRecognizer failed for other UIGestureGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, gesture, uitapgesturerecognizer

I write `UIView` class called `myView1` by extending one exit View called `myView2`.
it has registered one `UITapGestureRecognizer` (called tap2) in `myView2`, and I also want to register one `UITapGestureRecognizer` (called tap1) in `myView1`.
I want to system call `tap1 first`, then call `tap2` if tap1 failed. So I call below method.

```
[tap2 requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tap1];

-(void)handleTap1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender{
    if () {
        // let tap1 failed, then call tap2.
    }
}
```

> The question is that : how to let tap1 failed, then call tap2. tap2 is
>   the `UITapGestureRecognizer` of super class myView2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tap gesture could be recognized by one view at the same time refer to the iOS event response chain. For the same type gesture recognizer, `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` won't help you a lot, as I know.

If the `tap1 failed` condition depends on your private logic, you should implement the event forward manually by yourself. If there are really touch gesture conflicts exist among them, implement the `UITapGestureRecognizer`/`UIGestureRecognizer`'s delegate to identify their states including begin/move/end points.